# Formatting long pattern matching

Tags: haskell, code-formatting

I want format this function:

```
getEnv :: [Func] -> ([Char] -> RetType)
getEnv [] = (\_ -> undefined)
getEnv ((Func (RetTypeType t) (Ident fname) _ _):fs) = (\x -> if x == fname then t else getEnv fs)
```

The problem is caused by a long pattern matching, and for now I don't want to change the names of constructors. Also the right part of the function at the third line is not easy to formatting for me.

Although is not matter of life or death, I'm curios how you format this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, you have two possibilities:

Something like this:

```
getEnv ((Func 
          (RetTypeType t) 
          (Ident fname) _ _)
       :fs) 
    = (\x -> if x == fname then t else getEnv fs)
```

or you can use pattern guards:

```
getEnv (h:fs)
  | Func a b _ _ <- h,
    Rectype t <- a,
    Ident fname <- b 
  = (\x -> if x == fname then t else getEnv fs)
```

You could furthermore avoid the lambda:

```
getEnv (h:fs) x
  | Func a b _ _ <- h,
    Rectype t <- a,
    Ident fname <- b 
  = if x == fname then t else getEnv fs
```

The downside with "open" pattern guards may be that the compiler cannot decide anymore whether your patterns are exhaustive.

As @leftaroundabout points out, we can put it even more clearly thus:

```
getEnv (h:fs) x
  | Func a b _ _ <- h,
    Rectype t <- a,
    Ident fname <- b,
    x == fname         = t
  | otherwise          = getEnv fs
```

This will also let the compiler know that all possible forms of the head of the list are covered, so this I'd term the most preferred way to do it.

Comment: When you're already at pattern guards, why not also include the `x==fname` condition there? It fits perfectly. — For another thing, I prefer to put the commas at the beginning, aligned with `|` as is quite common style in Haskell (but of course, a matter of taste).

Comment: @leftaroundabout See, I for may part hate it when the line starts with commas. Apart from that. I'll edit my post to show the `x==fname`

Answer (score 2):

I would usually simply do

```
getEnv :: [Func] -> ([Char] -> RetType)
getEnv [] = (\_ -> undefined)

getEnv ((Func (RetTypeType t) (Ident fname) _ _):fs) 
          = \x -> if x == fname then t else getEnv fs
```

---

However I'd be inclined if I was doing a lot of that to use record syntax

```
data Func = Func {returnTypeType :: RetTypeType,
                  identifier :: Ident,
                  .... }
data RetTypeType = RetTypeType {unRetTypeType :: RetType}
data Ident = Ident {unIdent:: String}
```

so I could write

```
getEnv :: [Func] -> ([Char] -> RetType)
getEnv [] = (\_ -> undefined)
getEnv (f:fs) = \x -> if x == ident f 
                      then unRetTypeType.returnTypeType $ f 
                       else getEnv fs
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I try to keep patterns simple. Usually it's just one constructor with variables or underscores as it's arguments. Exception: built-in constructors like (:) or (,) don't count. So, if you have that kind of pattern-matching, I think you are doing something wrong.

Secondly, I would just split the line at '=' and be happy.